# My spanish text is not being decoded on my Ionic Hybrid App

Tags: string, ionic-framework, character-encoding, special-characters, decode

I'm using code like {{user.city}} in one of my templates to pull data from my MySQL DB on my Ionic Hybrid App.

On my frontend, For a value like

> Bogotá

I get

> Bogot&aacute

I made sure to set my DB collation to utf8_unicode_ci.

I tried searching and it seems I need to decode the entities, but I haven't been able to do so.I tried using:

```
<div ng-bind-html={{user.city}}></div>
```

Please bare in mind I have several values like this, not only one.

I'm also using an Ionic App I got from a code market, and I'm not very ionic-savvy, so if you could provide detail I would be very grateful!

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the locations in php.

Then in your controller:

```
$http.get("path").success(function(response) {
   var res =response.results;
   var locationtext =[];
   for (key in res){
     //in this case your locationsTEXT is the locations from the API
     locationtext.push(JSON.parse(res[key].locationsTEXT));
   }
   $scope.city = locationtext;
}
```

In view:

```
<ion-list>
 <ion-item ng-repeat="point in city track by $index"> 
        <p>{{point}}</p> 
 </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Keep in mind that, above code is a general solution. You must adapt this code according to your variables and needs.

Hope this helps!